# Show unique data between two tables after strings are split

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I got 2 tables which both contain 4 columns. I want the following things within my query:

1. When the first 3 columns of both tables are the same then
2. Check the 4th column and split the text between the `;`
3. If the text is 100% the same (not looking to the order)
4. Then show the differences between those two tables

The tables look like this for example:

table1:

```
 c1 |c2 | c3| column-text
------------------------------
| a | a | a | hello          |
------------------------------
| a | a | b | text           |
------------------------------
| a | b | a | just;an;example|
------------------------------
| a | b | b | st0ckexchange  |
------------------------------
```

table2:

```
 c1 |c2 | c3| column-text
------------------------------
| a | a | b | text           |
------------------------------
| a | a | a | everyone;hello |
------------------------------
| a | b | a | example;just;an|
------------------------------
| a | b | b | stackoverflow  |
------------------------------
```

The result would be:

```
 c1 |c2 | c3| column-text-t1 | column-text-t2
----------------------------------------------
| a | b | b | hello          | everyone;hello|
----------------------------------------------
| a | b | b | st0ckexchange  | stackoverflow |
----------------------------------------------
```

At the moment I'm using this query:

```
Select table1.c1, table1.c2, table1.c3, table1.column-text, table2.column-   text
from table1 
join table2 on table1.c1 = table2.c1 
            and table1.c2 = table2.c2 
            and table1.c3 = table2.c3
where table1.column-text <> table2.column-text
```

But this doesn't solve the problem when the strings in column-text are split with `;` and mixed.

Sorry if the question is a bit vague, I had a lot of trouble trying to explain the problem.

Comment: You should fix your data structure.  You should not be storing lists of things in a delimited string.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Youre totally right, but I do get this data from another program which I am just reading out. I have nothing to do with how they deliver their data to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @Table1 table (c1 varchar(5), c2 varchar(5), c3 varchar(5),[column-text] varchar(50))
Insert Into @Table1 values
('a','a','a','hello'),
('a','a','b','text'),
('a','b','a','just;an;example'),
('a','b','b','st0ckexchange')

Declare @Table2 table (c1 varchar(5), c2 varchar(5), c3 varchar(5),[column-text] varchar(50))
Insert Into @Table2 values
('a','a','b','text'),
('a','a','a','everyone;hello'),
('a','b','a','example;just;an'),
('a','b','b','stackoverflow')


;with cte as (
Select *,Hits = sum(1) over (Partition by C1,C2,C3,Value)
 From (
        Select Src=1,* From @Table1
        Union All
        Select Src=2,* From @Table2
      ) A
 Cross Apply string_split([column-text],';') B
)
Select A.c1 
      ,A.c2
      ,A.c3
      ,[column-text-t1] = (Select max([column-text]) from @Table1 where c1=A.C1 and c2=A.c2 and c3=A.c3)
      ,[column-text-t2] = (Select max([column-text]) from @Table2 where c1=A.C1 and c2=A.c2 and c3=A.c3)
 From  cte A
 Where Hits=1
 Group By A.C1,A.C2,A.C3
```

**Returns**

```
c1  c2  c3  column-text-t1  column-text-t2
a   a   a   hello           everyone;hello
a   b   b   st0ckexchange   stackoverflow
```

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=46a901223e41f5f837ea866981efed3b

Comment: What I run it on http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2f9c2e9e7d2e2fcc9bb706a942eda524 it doenst show the `hello and everyone;hello` tho?

Comment: @wouterdejong corrected.  I had a trailing HAVING clause.  Thiw was removed and the link updated

Comment: @wouterdejong I added the table variables just as a demonstration.  Just modify the 1st query and put in your actual table names

Comment: Thanks now I see, I still testing it with my actual table names, but get an incorrect syntax near `)`

Comment: @wouterdejong Did you replace all (at)Table1 and (at)Table2  There are 4 in total

Comment: Yes John I did, I still have a few issues it seems, do you mind talking further in a private chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137897/discussion-between-john-cappelletti-and-wouter-de-jong).